# iOS app (or similar) to view source of web page

Tags: gratis, ios, source-code, safari

I am looking for an iOS app that lets me easily view the source of the web page in Safari.

Requirements:

- preferably free (but no more than £1 if not free)
- runs on iOS 8 (preferably 7 as well)
- view source directly from Safari (and, if possible Chrome)
- syntax highlighting for Javascript, HTML, and CSS (anything else is a bonus)
- preferably a 'save' button for the source code for future reference

I'd rather the data didn't go through any third party server, and everything happens locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [View Source – HTML, JavaScript and CSS](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/view-source-html-javascript/id917660039?mt=8)

View Source is an app which adds an iOS 8 extension to Safari to allow you to view the source code of a webpage.

The app includes syntax highlighting and the code can be emailed/copied/exported. The app also includes a resource browser and DOM explorer similar to the developer tools in browsers.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great! Any idea whether this goes through a server?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Not a third-party server, no. It gets the page from the original server that the page is located.

Comment: Cool, accepted :)